# how to get this list to filter by a business week with parameters set for Monday-Sunday?

Tags: java, sql

This query generates all upcoming appointments for the week but its not returning the appointments from this week that have already occurred. The logic is flawed and I have tried everything.

```
        ObservableList<Appointments> appts = AppointmentsDAO.getAppts();
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        LocalDateTime startWeek = now.with(DayOfWeek.MONDAY);
        LocalDateTime endWeek = now.with(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY);
       
        FilteredList<Appointments> appointmentsFilteredList = new FilteredList<>(appts);
        appointmentsFilteredList.setPredicate(row -> {
            LocalDateTime start = (row.getStartTime().toLocalDateTime());
            if (startWeek.isAfter(start)  || endWeek.isBefore(start)) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
        appointmentsTableView.setItems(appointmentsFilteredList);
        appointmentsTableView.refresh();
    }
```

I created this lambda based of a sql statement which was :

```
"SELECT * FROM appointments AS a INNER JOIN contacts AS c " +
        "ON a.Contact_ID=c.Contact_ID WHERE YEARWEEK(start) = YEARWEEK(NOW())"
```

The sql worked perfect but I'm trying to eliminate it. Can somebody point me into the direction I need to go in? I'm assuming it has to do with the `startWeek` parameter and adding minus weeks one yields results for the previous week to which I do not want. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: No way to help you. You neglected to explain what is `Appointment` and what is returned by `Appointment#getStartTime`. You did not explain the data type of the relevant columns. And what exactly does `YEARWEEK` function do? And we lack the details to determine if you understand the proper way to represent booking appointments.

Comment: By the way, I cannot imagine a case where calling `LocalDateTime.now` is the right thing to do. That class purposely lacks the context of a time zone or offset from UTC. So that class cannot be used to represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline.

Comment: sorry about that its returning a time stamp value....and the relevant sql columns return timeStamp but i have them casting to local date time in other parts of my code. Also the sql yearweek function returns the year and week number (a number from 0 to 53) for a specified date. which is how i was able to get the list of appointments only occuring in a specified week... I needed to show the current week bookings, and this is for a school assignment so we cant use any other libraries other then the local java api's so my options are rather limited in that regard.